# Subclassing Django class based views?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to warp my head around Django's new class-based views from 1.3.

I've done a bit of reading:

- http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/08/24/class-based-views-usage.html
- http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2011/12/29/class-based-views-django-13/

But the one thing I haven't seen an example of, or how to do is, can several views subclass a common 'parent' class, reusing the data from there? (Pardon my thrashing of the common nomenclature)

An example of what I am trying to do:

```
class MyParentClass(TemplateView):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     session_data = request.session
     other_variables = foovars
     return self.render_to_response(context)

class MyChildClassOne(TemplateView):
    template_name = "template_one.htm"

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
      resultant_data = foodata
      return {'data' : resultant_data }


class MyChildClassTwo(TemplateView):
    template_name = "template_two.htm"

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
      other_data = foootherdata
      return {'data' : other_data }
```

So that the only difference between the two child classes is the templates they use and the 'data' they return. Both views would also return session_data and other_variables from the parent class, and therefore not repeating "return session_data, other_variables" in every  child class.

Answer (score 4):

First, don't override your view's `get` method. That's dangerous for several reasons I won't go into here.

Anmyway, what you need is the `get_context_data` method, which returns the context dict which is being passed to the template.

So, both your child views should look something like:

```
class ChildView(ParentView):
    template_name = "foo"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChildView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'foodata': 'bardata',
        })
        return context
```

But this is pretty much how views work out of the box; why do you think you need to subclass from an additional custom view class?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way: Your parent class will return a variable called data in the context which will be set by the child class.

Example:

```
class MyParentClass(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        session_data = request.session
        other_variables = foovars
        context['data'] = data
        return self.render_to_response(context)

class MyChildClassOne(MyParentClass):
    template_name = "template_one.htm"

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = foodata
        return super(MyChildClassOne, self).get(request, args, kwargs)


class MyChildClassTwo(MyParentClass):
    template_name = "template_two.htm"

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = foootherdata
        return super(MyChildClassTwo, self).get(request, args, kwargs)
```

Both your child classes inherit from `MyParentClass`, whose `get` method automatically sets a variable named `data` into the context. The data values are provided by the child classes. Once done they call the parent's `get` method to perform the common operations, including rendering.